# Am I allowing 3 guesses or 2?

Tags: python

I am learning Python on Codecademy, and I am supposed to give the user 3 guesses before showing "you lose". I think my code allows 3 entries, but the website shows "Oops, try again! Did you allow the user 3 guesses, or did you incorrectly detect a correct guess?" unless the user guesses correctly within 3 trials. Can someone tell me what's wrong?

```
from random import randrange
random_number = randrange(1, 10)
count = 0
# Start your game!
guess= int(raw_input("Please type your number here:"))
while count < 2:
    if guess==random_number:
        print "You win!"
        break
    else:
        guess=int(raw_input("Please guess again:"))
        count+=1

else:
    print "You lose!"
print random_number
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition should be:

```
while count < 3:
```

To make it easier to understand, I suggest you start the counter in `count = 1` and write the condition like this:

```
while count <= 3:
```

Now it's more clear that exactly 3 repetitions are allowed. But let's see why your code was wrong:

- `count` starts at `0`, and it's true that `0 < 2`, so we enter the loop
- At the first failed attempt, `count` gets incremented to `1`, and it's true that `1 < 2` so we enter the loop once more
- At the second failed attempt, `count` gets incremented to `2`, and it's no longer true that `2 < 2` so we exit the loop

So you see, only two attempts were being considered.

Comment: I thought I was doing the right thing because the interpreter shows this: Please type your number here: 4
Please guess again: 6
Please guess again: 9
You lose!
7
None      In this case, I count it as 3 guesses.

Comment: @rollwaveroll the last guess isn't being taken in consideration, even if you entered the right number, it wasn't being tested - you already had exited the loop by then

Comment: changing the smaller than to smaller or equal to works just fine. Thank you for the explanation. Very helpful.

Comment: Because changing the loop counter as you suggest won't actually fix the program. The user is already being asked for three guesses (run the original code and see). Changing it as you suggest will allow the user to guess up to four times (the last one still is not considered).

Answer (score 3):

Your loop will indeed ask the user for three guesses. (As can be trivially seen by *running the code*—ignore those other answers telling you to change the loop condition, that's the wrong solution.)

The problem with your loop is a more subtle one: because of the way it's structured, the third guess is never tested! You can see this by setting `random_number` to a constant and guessing wrong twice, then right on the last try; you still lose.

Your best bet is to use a more straightforward loop structure, where the asking and the checking happens in the same iteration of the loop.

```
for attempt in xrange(3):
    guess = int(raw_input("Please enter a number: "))
    if guess == random_number:
        print "You win!"
        break
    print "Wrong! Try again."
else:
    print "You lose! The number was", random_number
```

If you want a different prompt on the second and subsequent guesses, try this:

```
prompt = "Please enter a number"
for attempt in xrange(3):
    guess = int(raw_input(prompt + ": "))
    if guess == random_number:
        print "You win!"
        break
    prompt = "Wrong! Try again"
else:
    print "You lose! The number was", random_number
```

Comment: I  was learning while loop, but yours looks smarter solving the same problem. can can elaborate the second one? I am not used to the way computer reads, so it looks strange to me. why does your second prompt on the same indentation with if? And what does else say here? Thank you.

Comment: It has the same indentation as `if` because it is executed after the `if`. (You don't need `else` here; you could use it if you wanted, but since the `if` breaks out of the loop, anything after it will be executed only if the `if` wasn't true anyway. I just removed it because it's not necessary.) You could use a `while` loop here if you wanted, but the `for` is simpler.

Answer (score 2):

You need `while count <= 2`. Your count starts at 0. Then it goes through the body of your loop once. Then it gets incremented to 1. Then it goes through your loop body another time. Finally, once it increments to 2, your `while` condition evaluates to false, and the loop body doesn't execute a third time.

Be careful with corner cases when you're setting up conditions. :)

Comment: Yes, it works after the modification. I will pay extra attention next time. Thanks.

Comment: This will give the user *four* guesses.